# Ayuda con jsoup metodo POST no me actualiza los valores en el sitio web

Tags: java, android

Hola estoy intentando actualizar un formulario de un un sitio web pero no me deja actualizar, creo que estoy enviando bien los parametros, se me ejecuta perfectamente y sin errores pero no se que esta pasando que no se actualizan los datos del formulario al revisar el sitio web usan aspnet,
he revisado por el navegador el metodo post que utilizan para actulizar el formulario que acontinuaciónn dejo.
mi codigo en el android studio

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voidArr) {
    Connection.Response execute = null;
    Connection.Response response = null;

    try {
          ********************más código arriba*****************************
                execute = Jsoup.connect("https://www.tuenvio.cu/villaclara/Account")
                        .validateTLSCertificates(false)
                        .timeout(12000)
                        .cookies(mapCookiesNauta)
                        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.122 Safari/534.30")
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .data("__EVENTTARGET", "ctl00$cphPage$btnSubmit")
                        .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
                        .data("__LASTFOCUS", "")
                        .data("__VIEWSTATE", event3)
                        .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", event4)
                        .data("Language", "es-ES")
                        .data("CurrentLanguage", "es-ES")
                        .data("Currency", "")
                        .data("ctl00$txtSearch", "")
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$HiddenField1", HiddenField1)
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtFirstName", name)
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtLastName", last_name)
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$myBirthdateSelector$edtDay", dd)
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$myBirthdateSelector$ddlMonth", m)
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$myBirthdateSelector$edtYear", aaaa)
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtIdNumber", ci)
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtAddress1", address)
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtAddress12", address1)
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$listCountry", "54")
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$listState", provincia)
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$listCity", municipio)
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtZip", "10400")
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtPhone", phone)
                        .data("ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtEmail", email)
                        .data("ctl00$taxes$listCountries", "54")
                        .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                        .execute();
                Document body =execute.parse();
                    if (body!=null){
                        Log.d("sadasd", "doInBackground: "+execute.statusCode());
                    }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Gracias de antemano si me pueden ayudar

Answer (score 0):

```
estos son los parametros del metodo post que en la parte de arriba no me deja ponerlo

__EVENTTARGET:” ctl00$cphPage$btnSubmit”
__EVENTARGUMENT:””
__LASTFOCUS:””
__VIEWSTATE:””
__EVENTVALIDATION:””
Language: “es-ES”
CurrentLanguage: “es-ES”
Currency:””
ctl00$txtSearch:””
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$HiddenField1: “400088351”
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtFirstName: “aaa+asd”
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtLastName: “aaaa+asdas”
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$myBirthdateSelector$edtDay: “23”
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$myBirthdateSelector$ddlMonth: “4”
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$myBirthdateSelector$edtYear: “1996”
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtIdNumber: “960423”
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtAddress1: “adasdasdasdasd”
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtAddress2:””
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$listCountry: “54”
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$listState: “712”
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$listCity: “7013”
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtZip: “10400”
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtPhone: “55565656”
ctl00$cphPage$accountControl$txtEmail: “asdasd@gmail.com”
ctl00$taxes$listCountries: “54”
```